# How set resizer icon on top?

Tags: html, css

```
.div {
     resize: horizontal;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

How set resizer icon on top?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705115/16688813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform:rotateX(180deg);

// and first inner element add again this property