# How to create a CSS selector based on the computed style and not on inline style?

Tags: css

It is possible to create a CSS selector that match inline style, like so:

```css
[style*='flex-direction: row'] {
  /* some properties */
}
```

Is it possible to do the same, but using computed style instead of computed style?

I tried to do it in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robinmoussu/1qufj6Lo/18/).

The last CSS selector correctly match the element when `flex-direction` is set inline in the HTML (something that I rather not do) as seen with the green background, but not when `flex-direction` is set with another CSS rule as seen with the red background.

---

Alternative that I wish to not do:

- Look in all my code where there are CSS rules that set `display: flex`, and create a sub-rule to set the cursor shape for the corresponding `.separator`.
- Use external dependencies

---

In case this is an XY problem, what I am trying to do is to create a way to resize flex element using vanilla js. So far, I’ve come to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358791/9643557), but being sure that I set the right `cursor` shape for all divider requires a lot of work.

Comment: There is this possibility, but - and with only a few minutes experimentation, in Chrome (Firefox doesn't claim support, yet) - I haven't found a way to make it work: [`@container,` "style container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container#style_container_queries).

Comment: Very interesting @DavidThomas I’m unfortunately stuck on a older engine (an embedded QtWebKit), but I’m keeping this idea for later projects.

Answer (score 2):

css selectors are not aware of the computed style, but you could do something with javascript.
Since `flex-direction: row` is the default computed style, you should first check if the element is an actual `display: flex`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('*')

elements.forEach(element => {
  const style = getComputedStyle(element)

  // If not flex, exclude
  if (style.display !== 'flex') return false

  // If it is, add class 'is-flex-row'
  if (style.flexDirection === 'row') {
    element.classList.add('is-flex-row')
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.in-css {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.filler {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 25px;
}

.divider {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: help;
}

[style*='flex-direction: row'] .divider {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.is-flex-row .divider {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style='flex-direction: row'>
  <div class=filler></div>
  <div class="divider">OK</div>
  <div class=filler></div>
</div>

<div class="container in-css">
  <div class=filler></div>
  <div class="divider">OK</div>
  <div class=filler></div>
</div>

<div class="container column">
  <div class=filler></div>
  <div class="divider">not supposed to work</div>
  <div class=filler></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "css selectors are not aware of the computed style" this is what I feared. I’m honestly surprised that it’s even possible to match on inline style. Your solution seems useful, but unfortunately, I set the flex-direction based on the width of the screen (among other things) using a css @media query, so I would need to detect and re-run some js code each time the screen size is modified to set/remove the `is-flex-row` class.