# Is it possible with primeNg v4.3.0 to pull a layout who is splitted in 2 parts right and left and resize?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

[image]

Is it possible in angular with primeNg v 4.3.0 and Angular 5 to resize 2 layouts in the same screen like the windows 10 explorer in the picture below ? Or is possible with pure css ?
If no, why ? And if yes, how is that possible? I tried anything ...
Thank you very much for your answers !!!!!!!

```
  <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-g-nopad">
     <p-panel>.... </p-panel> 
    </div>

    // wanna put here a vertical line and pull right left, so the 2 panels gonna be resized ...

    <div class="ui-g-10 ui-g-nopad">
     <p-panel>.... </p-panel>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not with PrimeNG, but it is simple enough to do on your own. See the second answer (with 9 upvotes) to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194469/best-way-to-do-a-split-pane-in-html

Comment: Thank you very much my friend ! I didn't know that the name for such a splitter that moves the panel right and left is "resizable split pane". Your answer was a great help for me !!!!!!!!!