how to show a dropdown under its nav link?
I am looking for a solution to display the dropdown menu under its link in the navbar, the problem here is that the dropdown is too large sometimes, and it goes off screen when it is wide (img below).
The select must be displayed under each link with its arrow and not exceed the screen, i did not know how to go further in my calculations so that the select is displayed in the center if its link is also close to the center of the screen.


Here a simple example: https://codepen.io/meruem92/pen/LYwLwRd
in this example the last nav links "Products A" and "Products B", their submenu goes off screen because it contains a lot of content, i don't know what to do in this case.
This is the html :
<div class="w-100">
<ul id="top_menu" role="menu" class="nav navbar-nav top_menu justify-content-center custom-flex-list">
    
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
    <a role="menuitem" href="/" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active">
        <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="18" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">Page d'accueil</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
    <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="11" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="" style="">Nous connaître</span>
    </a>
    <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="11" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto;"><div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 111.992px;">
                <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="Rectangle" loading="lazy" style="">
            </div>
            <section class="o_cc1 ifp_about_us">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">À PROPOS</h4>
                            <nav class="nav flex-column">                   
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                    Certifying
                                        body
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                    Careers at
                                        IFP Training
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside"> 
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">NOS ENGAGEMENT</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                    Quality
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        Educational commitment
                                </a>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
    <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle show active" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="true">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="12" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="underlined" style="color: rgb(42, 176, 119);">Nos solutions</span>
    </a>
    <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu show" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="12" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: 0px; right: auto;" data-bs-popper="static"><div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 103.531px;">
                <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="Rectangle" loading="lazy" style="">
            </div>
            <section class="o_cc1 ifp_our_solution">
                    <div class="d-flex ">
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside"> 
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">EVALUATION AND COMPETENCY-BASED
                                        MANAGEMENT</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        
                                            Competency-based management
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        On-the job
                                            skills
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside"> 
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">FORMATION PROFESSIONNELLE</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        
                                            Inter/Intra/customized
                                </a>
                                
                                
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        Work-linked
                                            training
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside"> 
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">FORMATION EN APPRENTISSAGE</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                
                                
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        Apprentice
                                            information
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                            <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">VALIDATION DES COMPETENCES</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        
                                            National and international
                                            certifications
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        
                                            IFP Training Certificate
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
    <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="14" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="" style="">Boutique</span>
    </a>
    <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="14" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: 0px; right: auto;">
<div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 85.2578px;">
    <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="Rectangle" loading="lazy" style="">
</div>
<section class="s_mega_menu_odoo_menu o_cc1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Ordinateurs &amp; Appareils</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs portables</a>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Moniteurs</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Télévisions</a>
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Électronique</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Caméra</a>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Promotions</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs</a>
                    
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid border-top s_mega_menu_odoo_menu_footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 pt8 pb8">
                <div class="s_social_media text-center o_not_editable" data-snippet="s_social_media" data-name="Social Media" contenteditable="false">
                    <h5 class="s_social_media_title d-none" contenteditable="true">Suivez-nous</h5>
                    <a href="/website/social/facebook" class="s_social_media_facebook me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Facebook">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/twitter" class="s_social_media_twitter me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Twitter">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/linkedin" class="s_social_media_linkedin me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="LinkedIn">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-linkedin m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/github" class="s_social_media_github me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="GitHub">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-github m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/youtube" class="s_social_media_youtube me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="YouTube">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/instagram" class="s_social_media_instagram me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Instagram">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-instagram m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/website/social/tiktok" class="s_social_media_tiktok me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="TikTok">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-tiktok m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></div>
    </li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
    <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="13" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="" style="">Ressources</span>
    </a>
    <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="13" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto;"><div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 93.8516px;">
                <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="Rectangle" loading="lazy" style="">
            </div>
            <section class="o_cc1 ifp_resource">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="heardermenu-inside"> 
                             <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">RESSOURCES</h4> 
                           <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                
                                
                                
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                                        
                                            Case studies
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
    <a role="menuitem" href="/event" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active">
        <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="24" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">Événements</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
    <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="21" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="" style="">Contactez-nous</span>
    </a>
    <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="21" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: auto; right: 0px;">
<div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 1190.84px;">
    <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="Rectangle" loading="lazy" style="">
</div>
<section class="s_mega_menu_odoo_menu o_cc1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Ordinateurs &amp; Appareils</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs portables</a>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Moniteurs</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Télévisions</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Écrans de bureau</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Projecteurs</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Électronique</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Caméra</a>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Promotions</h4>
                
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    
                    
                    
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Réseaux</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</section></div>
    </li>
    <li data-name="Language Selector" class="o_header_language_selector position-relative">
    
        <div class="js_language_selector  dropdown d-print-none">
            <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" class="btn border-0 dropdown-toggle nav-link btn-sm d-flex align-items-center fw-bold text-uppercase o_nav-link_secondary custom-list-langage">
<img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]" class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/fr.png?height=25" alt=" Français" loading="lazy" style="">
                <span class="align-middle">FR</span>
            </button>
            <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                    <a class="dropdown-item js_change_lang " role="menuitem" href="/en/shop" data-url_code="en" title="English (US)">
<img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]" class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/us.png?height=25" alt="English (US)" loading="lazy" data-lazy-loading-initial-min-height="" style="min-height: 1px;">
                        <span class="align-middle ">EN</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item js_change_lang active" role="menuitem" href="/fr/shop" data-url_code="fr" title=" Français">
<img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]" class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/fr.png?height=25" alt=" Français" loading="lazy" style="">
                        <span class="align-middle ">FR</span>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </li>
                            
</ul>

                        </div>

This is my js :
    document.querySelectorAll(".o_mega_menu_toggle").forEach(function (toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var dropdownMenu = toggle.nextElementSibling; // Sélectionne le dropdown associé
 
    dropdownMenu.style.width = "auto";
 
    var rect = dropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect();
 
    if (rect.right > window.innerWidth) {
      dropdownMenu.style.left = "auto"; // Supprime le positionnement par défaut
      dropdownMenu.style.right = "0"; // L'aligne au bord droit de l'écran
    }
 
    if (rect.left < 0) {
      dropdownMenu.style.left = "0"; // L'aligne au bord gauche de l'écran
      dropdownMenu.style.right = "auto"; // Supprime l'alignement à droite
    }
 
    if (rect.width > window.innerWidth) {
      dropdownMenu.style.maxWidth = window.innerWidth - 20 + "px";
      dropdownMenu.style.overflowX = "auto";
    }
 
    var arrow = dropdownMenu.querySelector(".o_mega_menu-arrow");
    var toggleRect = toggle.getBoundingClientRect(); // Position du lien
    var dropdownRect = dropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect(); // Position du dropdown
 
    var arrowLeft = toggleRect.left + toggleRect.width / 2 - dropdownRect.left;
 
    arrowLeft = Math.max(15, Math.min(arrowLeft, dropdownRect.width - 15));
 
    arrow.style.left = arrowLeft + "px";
  });
});

Here is some css:
.custom-flex-list {
display: flex;
gap: 12px;

.nav-item {
  div[data-name="Mega Menu"] {
    width: auto; /* Taille automatique basée sur le contenu */
    max-width: calc(100vw - 20px);
    padding: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  .o_mega_menu-arrow {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  section[class^="o_cc1 ifp_"],
  section.s_mega_menu_odoo_menu {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: max-content;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-subItem-title {
    color: #2c7da9;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 250px;
  }
  .heardermenu-inside {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 25px;
  }


  .custom_nav_link {
    padding: 20px 22px 20px 26px !important;

    span {
      padding-right: 10px;
      color: $primary-color;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: $font-montserrat;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
  }
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 0;

  > div {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0 4px;

    .custom-list-langage {
      display: flex;
      height: 33px;
      padding: 5px 27.5px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 11px;

      .o_lang_flag {
        width: 1.5em;
        height: 1.5em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        border-radius: unset;
        object-fit: unset;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.429) 1px 1px 1px;
      }
      &:after {
        top: 0px !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

}

Instead of using JS and pixels for the positionning, simply, try to use CSS flex for the whole submenu div: display: flex; justify-content: center

you can't do this,  the submenu should be in position: absolute because it's located inside the   and it must be displayed outside

Yes! Remove that absolute, even if it looks easier, it is your problem. Since you added the CSS afterward... You must let the browser do his things. Remember there is so many screen sizes and browsers, we could not test on them all. Using absolute positionning will certainly render differently between each browsers. Simply because, a "pixel" unit is not always the same width on all screens. Yes, CSS looks simple, but in reality is very hard, on the little details. Using JS, is adding one extra layer of difficulty. If you stick the way you shown, try out using the unit vw instead, and calc().

thanks for these explanations, but this is not about relative or absolut position of submenu, the problem here is how to correctly position the submenu when its link is at the end of the screen (right or left) so that it does not exceed the screen, i already tried using not using absolute position for the submenu, but we still have the same issue

Just for the knowledge, a menu could be done with just HTML, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189834/2494754 maybe there is something useful for you in there. You will see, as you are asking, the submenu is displayed naturally under the item.

please check this example that i took from your link and added some html so that it have the same issue:
do you see how the last link displays its submenu? that's exactly the problem I have
https://codepen.io/meruem92/pen/ExqvgyX

Not sure what is your issue then.

There is no position: absolute applied to .dropdown-menu, even though the menu expansion code seems to rely on it. The maxWidth of a menu should not be set dynamically — using CSS alone is sufficient. Code that closes the currently open dropdown menu is missing.
Optional: to prevent .o_mega_menu-arrow from moving during scrolling, it can be placed within the .nav-link. It is also highly recommended to create a mobile menu for smaller screens.


document.querySelectorAll(".o_mega_menu_toggle,.dropdown-toggle").forEach(function(toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var dropdownMenu = toggle.nextElementSibling; // Sélectionne le dropdown associé
    var closeCurrent = (dropdownMenu.style.display == "block");

    // Hide all opened dropdown menus
    document.querySelectorAll(".custom-flex-list .dropdown-menu").forEach(function(menu) {
      menu.style.display = "none";
    });
    if (closeCurrent) {
      return;
    }

    dropdownMenu.style.display = "block";
    dropdownMenu.style.left = "auto";
    dropdownMenu.style.right = "auto";

    var rect = dropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect.right > window.innerWidth) {
      dropdownMenu.style.right = "0"; // L'aligne au bord droit de l'écran
    }

    if (rect.left < 0) {
      dropdownMenu.style.left = "0"; // L'aligne au bord gauche de l'écran
    }

    var arrow = dropdownMenu.querySelector(".o_mega_menu-arrow");
    if (!arrow) {
      return;
    }
    var toggleRect = toggle.getBoundingClientRect(); // Position du lien
    var dropdownRect = dropdownMenu.getBoundingClientRect(); // Position du dropdown

    var arrowLeft = toggleRect.left + toggleRect.width / 2;

    arrow.style.left = arrowLeft + "px";
  });
});
.custom-flex-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  list-style: none;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item div[data-name="Mega Menu"] {
  width: auto;
  /* Taille automatique basée sur le contenu */
  max-width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom-flex-list .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item .o_mega_menu-arrow {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item section[class^="o_cc1 ifp_"],
.custom-flex-list .nav-item section.s_mega_menu_odoo_menu {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 30px;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item .navbar-subItem-title {
  color: #2c7da9;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item .heardermenu-inside {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item .custom_nav_link {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.custom-flex-list .nav-item .custom_nav_link span {
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.custom-flex-list li:nth-child(5)>div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.custom-flex-list li:nth-child(5)>div .custom-list-langage {
  display: flex;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 5px 27.5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 11px;
}

.custom-flex-list li:nth-child(5)>div .custom-list-langage .o_lang_flag {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border-radius: unset;
  object-fit: unset;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.429) 1px 1px 1px;
}

.custom-flex-list li:nth-child(5)>div .custom-list-langage:after {
  top: 0px;
}

.custom-flex-list .dropdown-menu .d-flex,
.custom-flex-list .dropdown-menu .s_mega_menu_odoo_menu .container .row {
  display: flex;
}

.js_change_lang {
  display: block;
}
<div class="w-100">
  <ul id="top_menu" role="menu" class="nav navbar-nav top_menu justify-content-center custom-flex-list">
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active">
        <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="18" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">Page d'accueil</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
      <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="11" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="">Nous connaître</span>
      </a>
      <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="11" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto;">
        <div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 111.992px;">
          <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="^" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <section class="o_cc1 ifp_about_us">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">À PROPOS</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Certifying
                  body
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Careers at
                  IFP Training
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">NOS ENGAGEMENT</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Quality
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Educational commitment
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
      <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle show active" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="true">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="12" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="underlined" style="color: rgb(42, 176, 119);">Nos
          solutions</span>
      </a>
      <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu show" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="12" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: 0px; right: auto;"
        data-bs-popper="static">
        <div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 103.531px;">
          <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="^" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <section class="o_cc1 ifp_our_solution">
          <div class="d-flex ">
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">EVALUATION AND COMPETENCY-BASED MANAGEMENT
              </h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Competency-based management
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  On-the job
                  skills
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">FORMATION PROFESSIONNELLE</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Inter/Intra/customized
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Work-linked
                  training
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">FORMATION EN APPRENTISSAGE</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Apprentice
                  information
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">VALIDATION DES COMPETENCES</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  National and international
                  certifications
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  IFP Training Certificate
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
      <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="14" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="">Boutique</span>
      </a>
      <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="14" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: 0px; right: auto;">
        <div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 85.2578px;">
          <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="^" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <section class="s_mega_menu_odoo_menu o_cc1">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Ordinateurs &amp; Appareils</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs portables</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Moniteurs</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Télévisions</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Électronique</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Caméra</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Promotions</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid border-top s_mega_menu_odoo_menu_footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 pt8 pb8">
                <div class="s_social_media text-center o_not_editable" data-snippet="s_social_media" data-name="Social Media" contenteditable="false">
                  <h5 class="s_social_media_title d-none" contenteditable="true">Suivez-nous</h5>
                  <a href="#/website/social/facebook" class="s_social_media_facebook me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Facebook">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/twitter" class="s_social_media_twitter me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Twitter">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/linkedin" class="s_social_media_linkedin me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="LinkedIn">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-linkedin m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/github" class="s_social_media_github me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="GitHub">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-github m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/youtube" class="s_social_media_youtube me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="YouTube">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/instagram" class="s_social_media_instagram me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="Instagram">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-instagram m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/website/social/tiktok" class="s_social_media_tiktok me-3 ms-3" target="_blank" aria-label="TikTok">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-tiktok m-1 o_editable_media"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
      <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="13" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="">Ressources</span>
      </a>
      <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="13" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto;">
        <div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 93.8516px;">
          <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="^" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <section class="o_cc1 ifp_resource">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="heardermenu-inside">
              <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">RESSOURCES</h4>
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">
                  Case studies
                </a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <a role="menuitem" href="#/event" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active">
        <span data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="24" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name">Événements</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item dropdown True">
      <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="menuitem" class="nav-link custom_nav_link custom_nav_link_active dropdown-toggle o_mega_menu_toggle" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
        <span data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/a[1]/span[1]" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="21" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="submenu.name" class="">Contactez-nous</span>
      </a>
      <div data-name="Mega Menu" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/li[2]/div[1]" class="dropdown-menu o_mega_menu" data-oe-model="website.menu" data-oe-id="21" data-oe-field="mega_menu_content" data-oe-type="html" data-oe-expression="submenu.mega_menu_content" style="width: auto; left: auto; right: 0px;">
        <div class="o_mega_menu-arrow" style="left: 1190.84px;">
          <img src="/theme_ifpt/static/img/header/arrow_up.svg" alt="^" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <section class="s_mega_menu_odoo_menu o_cc1">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Ordinateurs &amp; Appareils</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Ordinateurs portables</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Moniteurs</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Télévisions</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Écrans de bureau</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Projecteurs</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Électronique</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Caméra</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <div class="heardermenu-inside">
                <h4 class="navbar-subItem-title text-uppercase h5 fw-bold mt-0">Promotions</h4>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0" data-name="Menu Item">Réseaux</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li data-name="Language Selector" class="o_header_language_selector position-relative">
      <div class="js_language_selector  dropdown d-print-none">
        <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" class="btn border-0 dropdown-toggle nav-link btn-sm d-flex align-items-center fw-bold text-uppercase o_nav-link_secondary custom-list-langage">
          <img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]"
            class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/fr.png?height=25" alt=" Français" loading="lazy"
           >
          <span class="align-middle">FR</span>
        </button>
        <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
          <a class="dropdown-item js_change_lang " role="menuitem" href="#/en/shop" data-url_code="en" title="English (US)">
            <img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]" class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/us.png?height=25" alt="English (US)" loading="lazy" data-lazy-loading-initial-min-height="" style="min-height: 1px;">
            <span class="align-middle ">EN</span>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item js_change_lang active" role="menuitem" href="#/fr/shop" data-url_code="fr" title=" Français">
            <img data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="973" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/img[1]" class="o_lang_flag " src="/base/static/img/country_flags/fr.png?height=25" alt=" Français" loading="lazy">
            <span class="align-middle ">FR</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



